# Смена картинки при нажатии

Tags: html, css

Как сделать в html, чтобы при нажатии кнопки картинка менялась на другую и так далее?

Comment: >картинка менялась на другую и так далее

И как далее?

Comment: и **ТАК** далее. Написали же. ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img src='abc.jpg' onclick='this.src="def.jpg"' />
```

Более сложные примеры тут тоже рассматривались. Поищите по слову "Галерея"

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, можно нажать галочку.